# get reference of the application window in the succeeding classes IPHONE app

Tags: iphone, tabs, uinavigationcontroller, uitabcontroller

I am adding tab controller on my 4th screen. Up to 4th screen my navigation bar is visible
    now on the 4th screen when i am adding Tab Controller to the window, navigation bar is getting disappeared...

```
code written in the tabbedController class is :




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    FirstTabScreen *firstTab = [[FirstTabScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    SecondTabScreen *secondTab = [[SecondTabScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    firstTab.title=@"First";
    firstTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"small_star.png"];
    secondTab.title=@"second";
    secondTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"small_star.png"];

    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     firstTab,
                                     secondTab,
                                     nil];

  //  self.tabWindow = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow ]subviews ] lastObject];

    //self.tabWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   // self.tabWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow ];
    //self.tabWindow = self.appDelegateAccess.window;
    self.tabWindow = self.appDelegateAccess.window;
    [self.tabWindow addSubview:tabController.view];
    [self.tabWindow makeKeyAndVisible];


  //  [self.view addSubview:tabsContainer.view];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong....
i think I am not referencing the root window for adding the tab controller ..
it it is the case please suggest me the way to take root window for adding tab controller

[image: this is third screen...]

[image: this is 4th screen]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you adding the tabbarcontroller in the window. why dont you add it in self.view ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make object of tabBar in YourAppDelegate. And write following code in following methode

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    FirstTabScreen *firstTab = [[FirstTabScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    SecondTabScreen *secondTab = [[SecondTabScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    firstTab.title=@"First";
    firstTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"small_star.png"];
    secondTab.title=@"second";
    secondTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"small_star.png"];

    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     firstTab,
                                     secondTab,
                                     nil];

    /*
        Your Other Code
    */
}
```

Then in your third View controller's .m file import your appDelegate like..

```
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"
```

Last Step write following code on selecting a row of your third view controller...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     YourAppDelegate * appDel = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate];
     [appDel.window setRootViewController:appDel.tabController];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add navigation controller separately,

Try this,

```
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
FirstTabScreen *firstTab = [[FirstTabScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
SecondTabScreen *secondTab = [[SecondTabScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navControllerOne = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstTab];
navControllerOne.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navControllerOne.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
navControllerOne.tabBarItem.title = @"First";

UINavigationController *navControllerTwo = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: secondTab];
navControllerTwo.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navControllerTwo.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
navControllerTwo.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";

tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         navControllerOne,
                                         navControllerTwo,
                                         nil];

      //  self.tabWindow = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow ]subviews ] lastObject];

        //self.tabWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       // self.tabWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow ];
        //self.tabWindow = self.appDelegateAccess.window;
        self.tabWindow = self.appDelegateAccess.window;
        [self.tabWindow addSubview:tabController.view];
        [self.tabWindow makeKeyAndVisible];


      //  [self.view addSubview:tabsContainer.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

great !!!! it fixed ...

I have removed

```
 self.tabWindow = self.appDelegateAccess.window;
    [self.tabWindow addSubview:tabController.view];
    [self.tabWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and added only one line

```
[self.view addSubview:tabController.view];
```

Finally it worked !!!

Thanks Rohit ..